# Should I report a colleague that may have broken intellectual property rules?

Tags: software-industry, colleagues, contracts, unprofessional-behavior

I'm a team leader for a large hi-tech company and I've been given ownership of a new project which we are planning to patent. Recently, a colleague of mine emailed me an article that reviewed the state of current technology as he believed the article was based on our research and must have been written by an ex-team member.

I recognized that this article was published by my manager (as he's used the pseudonym before). But I don't see anything there that jeopardizes our patent or explicitly gives away company secrets. I approached him about it and he claimed that he hasn't done anything wrong.

I have not told anyone that it was him. **Do I have a responsibility to let my superiors know so that they can decide if he's broken any rules?** I don't want to muddy his name if he's not done anything wrong.

Comment: You: "I don't see anything there that jeopardizes our patent or explicitly gives away company secrets" Your manager: "he claimed that he hasn't done anything wrong". So what's the issue here?

Comment: @JanDoggen I think that people may be unhappy with him for it, even if it's not an actual breach of contract.

Comment: @JanDoggen Also, it's not clear to me if you are saying I should report it or not.

Comment: @My other account 
What you're saying is you don't see any problem with the article, the manager agrees, your colleague didn't explicitly says that there are problems either. Where's the issue? 
Also nobody knows that you know that the pseudonym is your manager's, except your manager.

Comment: Passing on such information to someone that knows less about the details of the IP but that has more power to make decisions can only increase the opportunity for bad judgement. If this is just a review article surveying the current state of technology, there is no need to raise concern. Don't report it unless you want to create difficultly for your team, manager and yourself. What positive outcome do you think will occur if you report it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, why would you think this was a good idea?**

I am sorry to be firm, but there is no way you should be reporting this. The question you ask doesn't even justify your line of thinking.

1. You don't think anything wrong has been done. If you don't think anything wrong has been done, then there is nothing to report, end of story. Asking strangers on the internet for thoughts should absolutely not sway you, either.
2. Escalating this to management will make you look like someone who cannot make practical decisions about  real issues. This will harm your career.
3. You've raised it to your manager already (so he knows you know). Your question implies you are the only person who knows your manager is the author. If you *do* escalate this, when it gets mentioned to your manager your manager *will* know you raised this. Nobody likes snitches, especially when they're the target of the snitches', uh, snitching. You would be sinking your relationship with your boss (bad idea) over what you yourself describe as a non-issue (worse idea).
4. I'm not even sure where I would stand if you thought it *was* a breach of company confidentiality. I could well see a scenario where it could come back to bite you even if you were bringing up an issue the company would be concerned with. What would you gain?

In the end, explicitly naming people when you report issues is a very dangerous game to play. It is one thing when you feel *morally* compelled to do so (also, it probably won't end well for you). When you *don't* feel morally compelled to do so, it is completely and utterly another thing, in a different ball park, on a different planet. It isn't going to help you sleep better at night, and **it could well bite you in the ass. Don't. Do. This.**

Comment: I think point 1 sums it up. I should trust my own judgement.

Comment: 'Snitches' Really? The OP is not a lawyer and does not know the details of any contracts agreed to by his previous manager. This is absolutely something that should be brought up higher up the food chain. If the OP's previous manager is in violation of a contract and it is found out that the OP knew about it that could mean the OP is on the hook.

Comment: Never report anything for fear of repercussions -- got it.

Comment: @bdimag sure, that's one way (i would add, the wrong way) of reading my answer.

Comment: @Nahkki the OP doesn't think there is a problem. You should not go reporting things in the workplace as problems when you don't think they're problems. It makes you look a bit odd.

Comment: @bharal - Actually in asking the question the OP is showing that they don't know if it's a problem or not. Additionally the OP didn't say it wasn't a problem but that as far as they could tell it doesn't "jeopardize our patent or explicitly give away company secrets" which is a far distance from "I think it's OK". You should discuss things with your in the workplace if they could be an issue, not whether or not only if you think there is a specific 'problem'. Trusting the word of the person who is doing this as the "yeah it's ok" metric is foolish at best.

Comment: @Nahkki No idea what your idea of "OK" is, but to me, not thinking something is a problem because i cannot find a problem means that ... something isn't a problem, and it is OK. But fine, you start acting like a lawyer in *your* company (assuming you aren't already a lawyer), and irritate the senior management with your oddball ideas. I will just stick to doing what I'm qualified to do. Looks like the OP will too.

Comment: @bharal - Bringing this up to someone in management in the company who *isn't* the one involved is hardly acting like a lawyer. The folks in my chain of command are always happy to answer questions when I am unsure of a situation and how it should be handled. *NOT* asking someone is acting beyond your qualification, if you aren't a lawyer you(generic) should ask someone who is or at least who has familiarity in that arena.

Comment: @Nahkki seriously? I am a java developer. I saw there was some COBOL code at work. Should I alert to management that COBOL should be phased out? I am a Janitor at a bank. I saw a senior banker having lunch with a client. Should I alert to management the potential for breach of compliance? I am a lawyer. I saw a manager talking to an very attractive junior employee in a normal way. Should I alert to management that sexual harassment/favouritism may be occurring? Note in all the cases listed "I" would say I don't think anything wrong has happened.

Comment: @bdimag, there are definite repercussions here and one has to consider what good can come of reporting something like this. In this case, there is _CLEARLY_ little to be gained and a lot at risk for the OP in reporting this.

Answer (score 5):

Review your company's ethics policy or manual if they have one.  Some companies oblige you to raise this type of concern or else face consequences later if it turns out to be an issue that you were aware of and did nothing about.

Comment: i find the company handbook to be a tool for the company to point to later on, when something goes bad, and say "look, we have a culture of not-bad". Making a decision **solely** based on the company handbook is a bad idea, it is there to protect the company, not the employee. The advice it gives is not for the employee's benefit, but really for the company's.

Comment: @bharal Of course you should not act blindly, but this extends to not blindly following the "Keep your head down and mind your own business" mantra.

Comment: @bharal The OP themselves doesn't believe that any transgression occurred and bharal's advice is based on that. I wouldn't qualify his advice as "blindly following the 'Keep your head down and mind your own business mantra'" bharal is right that the company's employee handbook is designed to protect the company - Which is why we should all be aware and wary about the damn thing because that's where the reasons why you are getting fired come from. It's obvious that the company's employee handbook is not the only guide for action.It's also obvious that the handbook is what they'll use to get you

Answer (score 1):

He says he didn't do anything wrong and from your own reading of his article, you apparently agree. The final determination, however, may have to be done by someone else. You could pass the article along to management and have them get someone to vet it, with the caveat that you see nothing wrong with the article, but you are passing it along as a matter of due diligence, without inferring anything about anyone. As Ronald Reagan used to say: "Trust and verify"

The only way his name could get muddied is when someone is immature enough to make accusations without substantiation. Of course, if my management is the kind that shoots first and asks questions later, I would probably not pass it on to my management. Because my attitude would be that there is no need to get someone shot over what is most probably nothing - I am saying this from the jaundiced perspective of someone who was "investigated" once by my own management - They were great as people, OK as managers but it came to investigations, they were the Keystone Kops.  And somehow, the accusation kept living a lot longer than any finding that the accusation was without substance.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're making a strong case for the OP to NOT pass along the article. Did any good come out of that "investigation"? Under what circumstances would such an investigation be warranted?

Comment: @teego1967 It was an accusation made about me to me by a third party - a Vice-P of the firm - that I had sexually harassed an intern. I established that: (a) I had never been alone with that intern at any time during her employment - and the alleged victim and the people in her department confirmed that;and (b) neither the victim nor anyone else around her was aware that I had sexually harassed her. I was in the clear but that gratuitous accusation soured my relationship with the firm for good, in particular because the firm kept insisting that the accusation was well founded.

Comment: @teego1967 The best part of the joke is that I had to walk my own management on how to investigate me i.e. talk to the witnesses and ask them if they had ever seen me act inappropriately with her. I'll give them that:  they followed my procedure i.e. talk to the victim, talk to the people who interacted with her and me, and cleared me. That was twenty years ago but I am still peeved about the incident to this day. And yes, I feel that I had been smeared. Of all my transgressions, why did they have to go after me over something that I hadn't committed.

Comment: @teego1967 In order to have an investigation, we gotta have an accusation, the accusation must have some basis in fact and it must be deemed credible. A routine due diligence check is anything but an accusation but you and I know that there IS management out there who can't tell the difference. And again, when you get self-appointed investigators on the job, anything can happen.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, I think you need to consider the sensitivity of the material and the possible outcomes of action or inaction.

Raising concern about something like this to executive management regardless of whether or not anything improper actually occurred will, at a minimum, destroy trust between you and the manager who wrote the article. So if you do that, you should be certain that his article is serious transgression that jeopardizes the IP. Otherwise you will ruin the relationship over nothing.

Moreover, given that even you believe that the material is not an issue, by forcing upper level management to make judgement call, you risk making yourself look like someone who needs validation for a trivial non-decision. Why would upper managers have a better ability to decide here? What can they offer, other than "authority", to resolve this matter?

The best thing you can do is to NOT raise concern and maintain a smooth working relationship.

Answer (score 0):

**No, don't**

Reasons why:

1. You are acting above your pay grade.  Whatever your manager is doing, it is his responsibility to ensure his actions are congruent with the directives from senior management.  This is not your issue.
2. You said yourself, nothing appears to give away confidential information.
3. He may well be doing this with the blessing of senior management.  If certain key words in an article lead back to your company's website or product brochures, this may be intentional.  This is not at all an uncommon practice.
4. You're just stirring up trouble.  If you don't see an explicit threat to your company, then there's no reason to get everyone else spinning in circles.